# AJAX form submitting the wrong row from dynamically generated rows of data

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am currently reading data from a database and displaying the returned data in a table. One column contains the ID of each row, which I pass to a modal like this:

```
<a href=".user_id<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" title="View and Edit User"> Edit </a>
```

The modal gets data from another php file I included, using:

```
require('user_info.php');
```

The right data for each row is displayed on the modal, as I 'GET' the id passed into the modal, and query the database and display the returned info on a form on the modal. I have been careful to use classes in identifying the form elements, as I intend to submit the form using AJAX. Part of the form is:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<div class="row form-group">
    <label>User ID</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input name="userid" type="text" class="form-control userid" value="<?php echo $prow['id'];?>">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Name</label> 
        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $prow['fullname'];?>">    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Folder</label> 
        <input name="folder" type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $prow['folder'];?>">        
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn form-control modify_user_info" value="Submit Modification">
</div>
```

The problem now is, no matter which row on the original table I edit and submit through a modal, it is the first row of the table that attempts to get edited. The modals display the right information based on the row selected, but submitting the form on the modal always returns the data on the first row to the php file handling the form submission.

Here's my javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.modify_user_info').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var userid          = $('.userid').val();
        var email           = $('.email').val();
        $.ajax
          ({
            type:   "POST",
            url:    "modify_user_info.php",
            data: { 
                "userid":           userid,
                "email":            email, 
            },
            success: function (data) {
              $('.result').html(data);
            }
          });
      });
    });
```

PS: Submitting the form without AJAX works fine.
Edit: I need to add that printing the id submitted by the form shows that it is the first row of the table that is submitted, not the selected row.

Comment: are you getting proper values for `var userid  = $('.userid').val(); var email = $('.email').val();` these varibles?

Comment: @JitendraYadav how do I check that? I suspect the JavaScript is the source of the error.

Comment: use `console.log(userid, email)` after getting values from fields. make sure it doesn't submit `return false` and then check browser console to see the output.

Comment: console.log(userid) returns the first id on the database, no matter which row is selected.

Comment: verify whether your code contains multiple fields with same class `userid` that would be an issue.

Comment: Since the modal is generated from a MySQLi query, looking at the source code once I submit the form using AJAX shows modals for each row. This means the first modal always gets submitted, even if I click on the 500th row. My challenge is to get the AJAX to know exactly which row I selected.

Answer (score -1):

Change your href tag and modal like this

```html
i hope you are using a foreach loop

then change your href tag and target modal like this

<a href="javaScript:void(0)" class="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#user_id_<?php echo $row['id'];?>">View</a>

and your target modal as

<div style="" class="modal fade mymodal" id="user_id_<?php echo $row['id'];?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: I am using mysqli_fetch_array to iterate over the rows and generate the modals.